# JSON / JQuery - get_fields( ... ) confusion

Tags: php, json, advanced-custom-fields

Thanks in advance for any clarity:

I havent worked directly with JQuery or JSON till recently and currently have an issue I dont understand.

A wordpress plugin that displays a sort of tv schedule --> displays on the deployment server when added but not on my development server. When I add the plugin the page sends me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field()
```

Here is the actual line of code:

```
$ScheduleDownload = get_field('tv_printable_schedule', 'options');
```

I'm uncertain but I have a feeling that that is a JSON query... however the code doesn't recognize it. 
Is JSON / Jquery installed incorrectly? Am i simply missing a basic understanding?

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: `get_field` is not a jQuery method, nor is it inheriently JSON related.  Without showing us the definition for `get_field`, there's no way for us to know what it does

Comment: `get_field` belongs to Advanced Custom Fields, from googling: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: Try to install the plugin on your dev server and check again, `get_field()` belongs to the plugin **ACF** and if you are not installing it, the function therefore is undefined

Comment: make sure the plugin which have 'get_field' function has installed in your wordpress.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library that runs on the client. This is PHP code running on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone .. here was the answer that aynber & TOH19 hit correctly:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/installation/

you need to install advanced custom fields via plugin on the WP site.

Thank you!